# Beamer presentation PaloAlto theme: How to add a block in the bottom of the pages

Tags: beamer, presentations, themes

Please consider this template:

https://da.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/thomas-jansson-ku-style-beamer

with PaloAlto theme.

I want to place a thin block in the bottom of the pages showing my institution on one side AND the words "Project presentation" on the other. The colors should be two different ones like the top( dark/light).
Something like:
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/radboud-university-beamer-(version-1)

**How do I add that line?**

Every time I find a template then the line is already given by the theme but I want to stick with PaloAlto

Comment: .... still active

Answer (score 1):

Something that could be useful:

```
\documentclass{beamer}[10]
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig, subfigure}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{srcltx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{kugreen}{RGB}{50,93,61}
\definecolor{kugreenlys}{RGB}{132,158,139}
\definecolor{kugreenlyslys}{RGB}{173,190,177}
\definecolor{kugreenlyslyslys}{RGB}{214,223,216}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme[numbers,totalnumber,compress,sidebarshades]{PaloAlto}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]



  \usecolortheme[named=kugreen]{structure}
  \useinnertheme{circles}
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm]{KULogo}}
%\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\title[Project presentation]{Sample Title}
\author[my institution]{Thomas R. N. Jansson}
\institute{Niels Bohr Institute \\ University of Copenhagen}
\date{6 June 2014}



\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage \vspace{-0.5cm}
}

\frame
{
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents%[pausesection]
}

\section{First section}

\frame{
\frametitle{Sample Frame Title No. 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
}

\subsection{Sample subsection}

\frame{
\frametitle{Sample Frame Title No. 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{itemize}
}

\section{Second section}

\frame{
\frametitle{Sample Frame Title No. 3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{block}{Something important}
Einstein's formula
$$E=mc^2$$
\end{block}
}


\end{document}
```